# How to install wildcard SSL certificate in ubuntu AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Installed JITSI but unable to enable audio and video ...it throw an error saying **SSL certificate** is required. Can I get the exact steps to install SSL in **ubuntu 16.04 instance** in AWS EC2.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu you can find the nginx conf file in the directory `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and you will find <your_domain>.conf file.

Edit the config file to point the SSL certificate

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/<your_domain>.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/<your_domain>.key;
```

More information on how to setup SSL certificate with Nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Answer (score 0):

Install certbot, it will place correctly your certificates.

```
sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core
sudo snap install --classic certbot
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Jitsi only works if it have SSL.